# How to monkey patch without calling the original method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to get through this exercise:

> Write a new new_map method that is called on an instance of the Array class. It should use the array it's called on as an implicit (self) argument, but otherwise behave identically.

Here's an rspec:

```
describe Array do   describe '#new_map' do
    it "returns an array with updated values" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
      expect( array.new_map{ |e| e + 2 } ).to eq( [3, 4, 5, 6] )
    end

    it "does not call #map" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      array.stub(:map) { '' }
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
    end

    it "does not change the original array" do
      array = [1,2,3,4]
      expect( array.new_map(&:to_s) ).to eq( %w{1 2 3 4} )
      expect( array ).to eq([1,2,3,4])
    end   
end
```

I tried things to make it work. Here's my code:

```
class Array
  def new_map(&block)
    map(&block)
  end
end
```

I passed two requirements of the rspec, but not the one that states: `it "does not call #map"`. I don't understand how I can not call `map` in the process of passing a block into it. Any help or a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't it call the original method ? just because ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is some sort of homework requirement, I'm guessing they just want you to implement your own `map` method

```
class Array
  def new_map &block
    return to_enum :new_map unless block_given? 
    arr = []
    each { |elem| arr.push block.call(elem) }
    arr       
  end
end
```

However, this is not a monkey patch. This is just defining a new instnace method on `Array` at run time.

Comment: Don't forget that when invoked without a block, `map` returns an enumerator. Oh, and you don't need `self`. Nice teeth.

Comment: I suggest a small change to deal with the blockless case: `if block_given?; arr = []; each { |elem| arr.push block.call(elem) }; arr; else; to_enum(:new_map); end; end; end`. Then `enum = [1,2,3].map; enum.each { |i| 2*i } #=> [2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with that. I'm still a bit confused. This tutorial was about monkey patching. Maybe the first part of the exercise was to show how to make use of a method without monkey patching it? The instructions on this part were a bit vague (or at least to me).

Comment: jaeming, I believe the question merely asks you to create an instance method on the class `Array` that is functionally equivalent to [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (without calling `map` from your method). Note the class `Array` includes the `Enumerable` "mixin" module, which why you can invoke `Enumerable` methods on `Array` instances. `Rspec` should include a test for the case where you method is invoked without a block (but if you were given those `Rspec` tests, don't worry about that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use yield to replace `"block.call(elem)"`

```
def new_map
    arr = []
    each { |item| arr << yield(item) }
    arr       
end
```